# Can jQuery manipulate inserted elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a freshman to jQuery. I think it's reasonable that jQuery could manipulate elements added by code, but I found it couldn't just now.

```
$(function(){
    $("#addVideo").click(function(){
         $("#publisher").append("<div id='choseType'><input type='button' value='video'> <input value='music' type='button'> <input type='button' value='X'></div>");
    })      
    $("#choseType input:eq(0)").click(function(){
     $(this).addClass("selected");
    })
})
```

Is it jquery's limitation or my code's fault? It seems if I put the second `click()` function into the first one it will run correctly, but it will only run once(if I remove the appended `#choseType`and append it again the second click won't work.).Then how do I manipulate code added elements? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#addVideo").click(function(){

        //create new content, and append to publisher
        //also, reference the new content
        var newContent = $("<div><input type='button' value='video'> <input value='music' type='button'> <input type='button' value='X'></div>").appendTo('#publisher');

        //then add a handler to input in the context of the new content
        $("input:eq(0)", newContent).click(function(){
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        });
    })    
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. And could you please tell me why I can't put the second click outside the first and why the second click() will only run once when simply added to the first one without referencing the added content?

Comment: @Wasabi when the second handler was executed, it only added click handlers to elements already on the page. It did not add handlers to new elements. when you added the new elements, no handlers were bound to them.

Answer (score 4):

Delegate the event to an element that is not dynamic:

```
$(document).on('click', "#choseType input:eq(0)", function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

And ID's are unique!

Comment: +1. Just to note that you must have jQuery 1.7 or up to use the on() function.