# Jquery doesn't recognize a printed ID

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I can't manipulate the cells of my table with JQuery

I have a jsp where I call other jsp with a JQuery/Post which prints a table dynamically

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    var usuario =  $("#Id").text();
    var s = "13";
    $.post("../Querys/select_subcategoria.jsp",{s:s,usuario:usuario})
        .done(function(data) {
            $("#tab-index-div").append(data);
        });
});
```

it appends into a div.

then I have this code that helps to do a click in the hole tr and then it triggers a link

```
$('#tab-search tr').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    if(href) {
        window.location = href;
    }
});
```

It works if I print the table in the same JSP, but doesn't work if I print it in the other JSP, I tried to append the data into a table, and just append the `<tr>`, but doesn't work too.

I think JQuery does not recognize the ID of the table

If anyone has any ideas it would be a great help.

Comment: Dynamic data handlers need to use event delegation.

Comment: I did this 

    `$(document).on('click', "#tab-search tr", function(){
         var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
            if(href) {
                window.location = href;
            }
    });`
 
I found the answer in

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377060/can-jquery-manipulate-inserted-elements

Answer (score 0):

Your click() won't handle dynamically added elements, you have to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method like this :

```
$('#tab-search').on('click','tr a', function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if(href) {
        window.location = href;
    }
)}
```

I didn't test but this is the idea.

In older jQuery version we had the live() function to manage these, but it is deprecated on newer versions.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#tab-search').delegate('tr', 'click', function() {
    var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    if(href) {
        window.location = href;
    }
});
```